# React Refs woth setState giving Maximum update depth exceeded.

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Helo guys, i trying to use Refs and to give `this.setState`inside his but it give:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

How i'm doing:

```js
ref = {
  (anchor) => this.setState({
    anchor
  })
} >
```

But when i use:

```js
ref = {
  (anchor) => this.state.anchor = anchor
} >
```

it works..

And in other component, i use `this.setState` also and it works perfectly, someone why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) is a special props in React. React will call the `ref` callback with the DOM element when the component **mounts**, and call it with `null` when it **unmounts**.  `ref` updates happen before `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hooks. So in the first example, when `ref` props callback function gets executed, before the mount you are changing the `state` using `setState`, so component again starts **mounting** due to state change. And now your are in **Infinite call** loop.

But in the second case, you are directly mutating the `state` which never should be done in React, and when you update the state by mutating directly the `state` it never kicks re rendering. So there is no **Infinite call** is happening. It mounted normally.

Note: `ref` is not a place to change the state. *`Refs` provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.* As per the doc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: just to highlight important part(so OP won't miss that): we should never put into `.state` something that is not used later in `render()`. So `ref` should be stored elsewhere, say into property of `this`

Comment: @skyboyer You are right!. But I think the OP just shown us the problematic part. But it is good that you made a note for future readers, which is true indeed.

Comment: Here is [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/v61x85nyn0) to reproduce the problem.. I couldn't create it in SO script editor, so leaving it here.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Thank you for your answer, i've understood, but i have a question..
How can i do this? Without to mutate state directly and to give error ?

I use like you in the your example and not give error..

Comment: Why do u need to `ref`? `ref` are to get an access to the native dom elemenet/component instance... not to update state..

Answer (score 2):

1) refs must *never* be stored as a part of the component state. Just assign it to the component's member like this:

```
<div ref={ x => this.anchor = x } />
```

2) The component's state *must never* be modified directly. No `this.state.x = something`, use setState so React could detect the change and make the UI update.

3) `setState()` *must not* be called directly from the `render()` (which causes infinite rendering loop).